# Can't publish the electron app from github

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-updater, electron-react-boilerplate

I just created my electron-react application and also I implemented the auto-update functionality. But unexpectedly I got some weird error logs from electron-builder.

I'm not sure how to resolve it. I tried different kinds of ways. I hope this community helps me. Thanks in advance.

This configuration works fine for developing local build and also after installed it's works fine as per expected. The problem only raises the `npm run package-deploy` command.

Am I doing anything wrong?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "analyzer",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "author": "Mohamed Jakkariya",
  "description": "This application used for analyzing the stock information and find useful data for trading in the better way.",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "*",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "csv-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-updater": "^4.3.9",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set BROWSER=none && react-scripts start",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "start-electron": "set ELECTRON_START_URL=http://localhost:3000 && electron .",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build-electron": "robocopy src/electron build/electron /S ",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js src/**/*.jsx",
    "package-build": "electron-builder build --win -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js --publish never",
    "package-deploy": "electron-builder build --win -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js --publish always"
  },
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "publish": {
    "provider": "github",
    "repo": "nift-analyzer",
    "owner": "MohamedJakkariya",
    "releaseType": "release"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/MohamedJakkariya/nift-analyzer/"
  },
  "build": {
    "productName": "Stock Analyzer",
    "appId": "com.mohamedjakkariya.nift-analyzer",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "win": {
      "icon": "./public/icon.png",
      "publish": [
        "github"
      ]
    },
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.8",
    "electron-builder": "^22.11.1",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2"
  }
}
```

**Error Logs**

```
> analyzer@1.2.1 package-deploy
> electron-builder build --win -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js --publish always

  • electron-builder  version=22.10.5 os=10.0.18362
  • cannot check updates  error=TypeError: update_notifier_1.default is not a function
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • loaded parent configuration  preset=react-cra
  • writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=12.0.8 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  • building        target=nsis file=dist\Stock Analyzer Setup 1.2.1.exe archs=x64 oneClick=true perMachine=false
  • building block map  blockMapFile=dist\Stock Analyzer Setup 1.2.1.exe.blockmap
  • publishing      publisher=Github (owner: MohamedJakkariya, project: nift-analyzer, version: 1.2.1)
  • uploading       file=Stock-Analyzer-Setup-1.2.1.exe.blockmap provider=GitHub
  • uploading       file=Stock-Analyzer-Setup-1.2.1.exe provider=GitHub
  ⨯ Cannot cleanup: 

Error #1 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getType' of undefined
    at GitHubPublisher.doUploadFile (C:\Users\MD\Desktop\stock-calc\node_modules\electron-publish\src\gitHubPublisher.ts:190:36)
    at GitHubPublisher.doUpload (C:\Users\MD\Desktop\stock-calc\node_modules\electron-publish\src\gitHubPublisher.ts:170:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at GitHubPublisher.upload (C:\Users\MD\Desktop\stock-calc\node_modules\electron-publish\src\publisher.ts:87:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
    at AsyncTaskManager.awaitTasks (C:\Users\MD\Desktop\stock-calc\node_modules\builder-util\src\asyncTaskManager.ts:65:25)
    at PublishManager.awaitTasks (C:\Users\MD\Desktop\stock-calc\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\publish\PublishManager.ts:228:5)
    at Object.executeFinally (C:\Users\MD\Desktop\stock-calc\node_modules\builder-util\src\promise.ts:23:3)

Error #2 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getType' of undefined
    at GitHubPublisher.doUploadFile (C:\Users\MD\Desktop\stock-calc\node_modules\electron-publish\src\gitHubPublisher.ts:190:36)
    at GitHubPublisher.doUpload (C:\Users\MD\Desktop\stock-calc\node_modules\electron-publish\src\gitHubPublisher.ts:170:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at GitHubPublisher.upload (C:\Users\MD\Desktop\stock-calc\node_modules\electron-publish\src\publisher.ts:87:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
    at AsyncTaskManager.awaitTasks (C:\Users\MD\Desktop\stock-calc\node_modules\builder-util\src\asyncTaskManager.ts:65:25)
    at PublishManager.awaitTasks (C:\Users\MD\Desktop\stock-calc\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\publish\PublishManager.ts:228:5)
    at Object.executeFinally (C:\Users\MD\Desktop\stock-calc\node_modules\builder-util\src\promise.ts:23:3)  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: Cannot cleanup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hurray! I fixed the issue myself. Thanks to myself. Here, it's the solution for my case. I hope it'll help someone in the future.

1. **package.json** should be like this,

```
{
  "name": "analyzer",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "author": "Mohamed Jakkariya",
  "description": "This application used for analyzing the stock information and find useful data for trading in the better way.",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-updater": "^4.3.9",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set BROWSER=none && react-scripts start",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "start-electron": "set ELECTRON_START_URL=http://localhost:3000 && electron .",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build-electron": "robocopy src/electron build/electron /S ",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js src/**/*.jsx",
    "package-build": "electron-builder build --win -p never",
    "package-deploy": "electron-builder build --win -p always"
  },
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/MohamedJakkariya/nift-analyzer.git"
  },
  "build": {
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "github",
        "owner": "MohamedJakkariya",
        "repo": "nift-analyzer"
      }
    ],
    "productName": "Stock Analyzer",
    "appId": "com.mohamedjakkariya.nift-analyzer",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "win": {
      "icon": "./public/icon.png",
      "publish": [
        "github"
      ]
    },
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.8",
    "electron-builder": "^22.11.1",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2"
  }
}
```

2. **Remove** -> **package.lock.json**.
3. **Remove** -> **node_modules**.
4. Type `npm install`.
5. Generate GitHub personal access token for that particular repo. (For my case it's a private repo)
   **Note:** Access token should be given the permission of **repo**.
6. Set env value of **GH_TOKEN** for an access token.

   1. Open PowerShell and then type

   ```
   [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("GH_TOKEN","<TOKEN>","User")
   ```
7. Run deploy command `npm run package-deploy`.

That's it! Happy coding.